# Error in Java Script aplication: Uncaught syntaxerror, Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

Well, this is the script (in JavaScript, by the way)

```
function verbox(origen,vi,titulo){
$("#fullbox").fadeIn('fast');
if (vi=="video") {
    $("#previewbox").fadeIn('slow');
    $("#previewboxinner").innerHTML='<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+origen+'?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
else if (vi=="foto"){
    $("#previewbox").fadeIn('slow');
    $("#previewboxinner").innerHTML='<center><img src="'+origen+'" alt="'+titulo+'"><br>+'titulo'+</center>';
}
}
```

I know it is a typo but I can't find it, would you help me to find it? Thanks you.

Comment: The syntax highlighting should help you. Also, along with syntax errors there are line numbers printed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
'"><br>+'titulo'+</center>';
```

to

```
'"><br>'+titulo+'</center>';
```

Comment: You may prefer `<br />` for compatibility with strict html and ancestral browsers

Comment: @lib3d No. Unless you use XHTML, you don't have to add this `/`. And you certainly shouldn't when using HTML5.

Comment: That was fast, thank you.

Comment: I included ancient IE versions. But you are right about HTML5.

Comment: Old IE versions were fine without the / too. It was only bad if you used a XHTML DTD.